# Laravel 5.2, Input::all() is empty

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have strange problem. On localhost everything is ok. But on my production website function `Input::all()` return empty Array.

For example `http:://mypage.com?action=run` etc.

nginx configuration

```
    server {
root /usr/share/nginx/www/g2g/public;
index index.html index.htm index.php;
server_name mypage.com www.mypage.com;

location / { 
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html /index.php;
}   

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

}

Comment: And where is your code ?

Comment: I am an advanced Laravel5 user and have yet to experience this problem myself.
Could it be that your production environment disallows input? If that is not the case, could you please post the context in which u use Input::all()?

Comment: In all examples, Input::all(), Input::get('somthing') not working. On localhost in all examples are working. Global problem on production website.

Comment: Is your apache rewrite or nginx conf setup correctly?

Comment: Is `$_GET` empty also?

Comment: I've edited post and I've added nginx configuration. In comment this was without formatting

Comment: @Pitchinnate Yes it is.

Comment: Nginx problem.
Should be.
`   location / { 
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html /index.php?query_string;
    } `

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, for help.

Should be.

```
location / { 
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html /index.php?query_string;
}
```

in nginx configuration file

Answer (score 0):

In nginx configuration, it should be this.

```
location / { 
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

This is important - **$query_string**

Hope much helpful with saving time.